# Is there any way to use xpath to filter/process literal result elements?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I'm working on a stylesheet to transform tables similar to IETF (i.e xhtml) tables, but column-oriented, to xsl-fo.

One of the first steps is to transform <col/> tags to <fo:table-column/> tags.
Unfortunately for some reason the authors of the XSL 1.1 spec didn't provide a way to transfer all attributes automatically from <fo:table-column/> to the table-cells in the corresponding column, and the attributes (with the exception of width) don't apply automatically, either (really dumb design decision, in my opinion -- [here is one of the Antenna House developers complaining about the same thing in 2001!](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/xsl-editors/2001AprJun/0031.html)).  Inheritance doesn't apply, either, as <fo:table-column/> doesn't have any children.

This leaves me with the task of figuring out what formatting attributes have been set for each column and applying them by hand to the appropriate table-cells.  How best to do that, though?  One thought I had was to place all the <fo:table-column/> nodes into a variable, but then how would I use xpath to process these nodes?  The other thought is there must be a way to do this using a temporary result tree, but have never used anything like this and am clueless about whether not this is possible, and if it is, how one would work with a temporary result tree.  I'm posting this question with labels XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 just to see if there **is** an answer, but I'm really constrained to using XSLT 1.0 for this problem.

**Edit:**  Someone requested a concrete example.  A source document fragment might look something like this:

```
<table>
  <col width="33%" font-weight="bold" border="1pt solid black"/>
  <col width="34%" span="2" color="red" background-color="gray"/>
  <col font-style="italic" align="center" background-color="yellow"/>
  <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr>
  <tr><td>dog</td><td>cat</td><td>mouse</td><td>elephant</td></tr>
  ...
</table>
```

i.e. a standard xhtml table, except with some attributes that would normally be represented using the style attribute.

Then natural translation would be

```
<table> -->  <fo:table>
<col/>  -->  <fo:table-column/>
<tr>    -->  <fo:table-row>
<td>    -->  <fo:table-cell>
```

However, there is a problem with this, namely none of the attributes in <table-column/> are automatically applied to the table cells in the corresponding column unless you specifically request that they be invoked using the *from-table-colum()* function (with the exception of width which *is* automatically applied).  So, for example, for a table cell in the **3rd** column of the table I would need to output the fo like this:

```
<fo:table-cell color="from-table-column()" background-color="from-table-column()>
```

and for a table cell in the **4th** column I would need to output

```
<fo:table-cell font-style="from-table-column()" align="from-table-column()" background-color="from-table-column()>
```

The question is how do you know which attributes to look for for the table-cells in a particular column?

Comment: An small example of the input and the requested output would be really helpful here, IMHO. Especially WRT to "*didn't provide a way to transfer all attributes automatically*".

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem ... this [answer of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29310046/4453460) explains how the `from-table-column()` function works; can't you just put the formatting properties on the `fo:table-column`, and refer to those values with `from-table-column()` in the cells?

Comment: @michael.hor257k -- I added a concrete example.

Comment: @lfurini -- Yes, you can put all the formatting properties in `fo:table-column`.  The question is how do figure out which of these apply to a particular <fo:table-cell> once you're in a template which is processing table cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Caveat***: I know nothing about XSL-FO; this is just something for you to use as a starting point.

The way I understood your question, you want each table-cell to have the same list of attributes as the corresponding `col` in the source document. This would have been very easy to accomplish by looking at the position of the currently processed `td` and using that to look up the `col` at the same relative position. However, since some of the `col` elements have a `span` attribute, this is not as easy as that.

The solution I would suggest is to start by "enumerating" the `col` elements, so that there are exactly as many of them as there are columns. With this in place, we can proceed as planned.

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="columns">
    <xsl:for-each select="/table/col">
        <xsl:call-template name="replicate">
            <xsl:with-param name="n">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@span">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@span"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>1</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/table">
    <fo:table>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>  
    </fo:table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tr">
    <fo:table-row>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="td"/>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="td">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
    <fo:table-cell>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($columns)/col[$i]/@*[not(name()='width' or name()='span')]">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">from-table-column()</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>  
    </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replicate">
    <xsl:param name="n"/>
    <xsl:if test="$n">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:call-template name="replicate">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n - 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>        
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input example, will produce the following **result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fo:table xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell font-weight="from-table-column()" border="from-table-column()">A</fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell color="from-table-column()" background-color="from-table-column()">B</fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell color="from-table-column()" background-color="from-table-column()">C</fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell font-style="from-table-column()" align="from-table-column()" background-color="from-table-column()">D</fo:table-cell>
   </fo:table-row>
   <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell font-weight="from-table-column()" border="from-table-column()">dog</fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell color="from-table-column()" background-color="from-table-column()">cat</fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell color="from-table-column()" background-color="from-table-column()">mouse</fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell font-style="from-table-column()" align="from-table-column()" background-color="from-table-column()">elephant</fo:table-cell>
   </fo:table-row>
</fo:table>
```

This is assuming the table cells themselves do not have spans; otherwise this could get much more complex.

Comment: Awesome!  I had thought of a solution like this, but didn't know how to use exslt.  Thanks for the example!

Answer (score 1):

Well with XSLT 1.0 a variable containing result nodes is a result tree fragment, to convert it into a node set to be apply to apply XPath or process the nodes further you would use `exsl:node-set` or similar e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="v1-rtf">
  <fo:table-column>...</fo:table:column>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="v1-ns" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" select="exsl:node-set($v1-rtf)"/>

<xsl:apply-templates select="$v1-ns/fo:table-column"/>
```

The only difference in XSLT 2.0 is that you don't need the `exsl:node-set` function and its conversion operation, you can use any variable with temporary trees directly e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="v1">
  <fo:table-column>...</fo:table:column>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:apply-templates select="$v1/fo:table-column"/>
```